# Wish to past triangle identifiers to shaders

Tags: javascript, opengl

I am using gl.TRIANGLES to draw a function where I past vertices and an index buffer to identify the vertices of each triangle.  I would also like the shaders to distinguish three types of triangles:  -1,0, and 1.    I realize I can set up a triplet set of numbers for each triangle and pass this buffer to an attribute variable of the vertex shader then on to the fragment shader via a varying variable.  However, that seems to be a lot of unnecessary data as I only need a single number per triangle.
 Is there a way to set up a buffer for gl.TRIANGLES so that for each triangle, a single number gets passed to the vertex shader?  I can then use a varying variable
 to pass it to the fragment shader.  Or will I have to set up duplicate 
triplets like (0,0,0) or (-1,-1,-1) for each triangle?

Comment: Send duplicate data, vertex data is very cheap so saving some bytes isn't worth it.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Also I just realized I can possibly set up a vec4 buffer for the vertices and include the triangle type in the fourth position so I wouldn't have to set up additional buffers and then just split out the vec3 vertex in the shader.   Will give that a try.

Comment: On second thought the vec4 approach may be a problem since I want the triangle type to be integer and the vertices are float.  May have to tinker with it.

Comment: It could work with separate attributes, but you could also cast the fourth float to an integer

Comment: Ok thanks.  In order for me to distinguish between the three types of triangles in the fragment shader using varying variables, the -1 and+1 I could easily do with:  if(vBC.x<0) and if(vBC.x>0).  However, will the fragment shader vary the "zero" variables as float so that I would not be able to use if(vBC.x==0)  or would the shader keep it in integer form?

Comment: Is each vertex used by only one triangle? Otherwise passing the triangle identifier as a vertex attribute will not work directly.

Comment: Each vertex is used by multiple triangles (it's a sheet of triangles).  I think I can get it to work:  my understanding is that the shader will vary the vertexIdentifierAttribute (-1,0 or 1) independently for each triangle even though one vertex is shared by multiple triangles.  Thus if the varying variable is varying positively, it's triangle ID=1, if it's varying negatively, it must be triangle ID=-1.  And I think if the varying remains at (integer) zero, then it must be triangle ID=0.  Not sure though.  Can't check it for a while now.  Will get back.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean:  I cannot associate the triangle ID with the vertex as a vec4 variable since it's varying will be used whenever the vertex is used.  Rather, I would have to set up an entirely new buffer similar to the index buffer defining three attributes to be fed into the vertex shader for every triangle.  That should work.